# form post action going to wrong URL

Tags: html, ajax

I have another personal website I want to post my form to, see code

```
<form name="requestPrint" action="www.mysite1.com/set_var.cgi" 
        method="POST">
        <input name="value" type="hidden" size="8" value="1"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="mypage.html"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="index" value="94"/>
        <input type="submit" value ="Print">
        </form>
```

However when the form posts it goes to www.mysite2.com/www.mysite1.com/set_var.cgi

Is there a way to point it to just www.mysite1.com/set_var.cgi?

Comment: Try adding http:// or https:// or // to the front of url otherwise it thinks you pointing to your present domain name..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the following:
`action="http://www.mysite1.com/set_var.cgi"`